# How to update the contents of a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Within a modal, I need to update the information shown there, every time it opens. But it seems like everything, keeps it in the cache.

[Previous question where the code is.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357458/do-not-cache-or-read-cache-angularjs-1-6-bootstrap-3-3)

Comment: Share more info and your code so that this can be answered.

Comment: I added a link to a previous question, there is the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Find the solution, using `$router` from AngularJS.
```

```js
var helloApp = angular.module('helloApp',["ngRoute"]);


 helloApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when("/", {
     templateUrl : "modal.html",
     controller: 'DataCtrl'
   })
   .when("/red", {
     templateUrl : "1.htm"
   })
   .when("/green", {
     templateUrl : "2.htm"
   })
   .when("/blue", {
     templateUrl : "3.htm"
   });
 });


 helloApp.controller("CompanyCtrl",['$scope',function($scope){

  $scope.numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  $scope.tableTitle = "SEMESTRE ";
  $scope.checked1 = false; //DELETE

  $scope.number = 7;
  $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
      return new Array(num);   
  }

  $scope.companies = [
                     { 'name':'Infosys Technologies',
                      'employees': 125000,
                      'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                      { 'name':'Cognizant Technologies',
                       'employees': 100000,
                       'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                       { 'name':'Wipro',
                        'employees': 115000,
                        'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                        { 'name':'Tata Consultancy Services (TCS)',
                         'employees': 150000,
                         'headoffice': 'Bangalore'},
                         { 'name':'HCL Technologies',
                          'employees': 90000,
                          'headoffice': 'Noida'},
                     ];
     $scope.vAddGroup = [

     ];

 $scope.addGroup = function(name){ 
  var index = -1; 
  var comArr = eval( $scope.companies );
   for( var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++ ) {
    if( comArr[i].name === name ) {
     index = i;
     break;
    }
   }
   if( index === -1 ) {
    alert( "Something gone wrong" );
   }

  $scope.vAddGroup.push({ 'name':comArr[index].name, 'employees':comArr[index].employees, 'headoffice':comArr[index].headoffice });
  $scope.checked1 = true;

  var d = document.getElementById("1"); // IDENTIFICADOR UNICO CADA MATERIA
  d.className = " subjectOK not-active";

 };


 $scope.addRow = function(){  
  $scope.companies.push({ 'name':$scope.name, 'employees': $scope.employees, 'headoffice':$scope.headoffice });
  $scope.name='';
  $scope.employees='';
  $scope.headoffice='';
 };

 $scope.removeRow = function(name){    
   var index = -1;  
   var comArr = eval( $scope.vAddGroup );
   for( var i = 0; i < comArr.length; i++ ) {
    if( comArr[i].name === name ) {
     index = i;
     break;
    }
   }
   if( index === -1 ) {
    alert( "Something gone wrong" );
   }
   $scope.vAddGroup.splice( index, 1 ); 
   $scope.checked1 = false;


   var d = document.getElementById(1); // IDENTIFICADOR UNICO CADA MATERIA
   d.className = " subject";
  };

 }]);



helloApp.controller('DataCtrl', function($scope, $http, $route) {
 console.log("DataCtrl");
 
 $scope.reloadData = function(){
  $scope.content = [];
  console.log("Reload before 2");
  $route.reload();

  console.log("inOpenModal2");
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.content = response.data.records;
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.contentWrong = response.config;
    });

  console.log("Reload after 2");

 };
 
  console.log("inOpenModal1");
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.content = response.data.records;
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.contentWrong = response.config;
    });

  
 
});


function closeModal(){
 $('.modalCloseID').modal('hide');
 //$('#inbox').remove();
 console.log("closeModal");
}

function initModal(){
 console.log("initModal");
}
```

```css
.subject {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    /* border: none; */
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white; 
    padding: 1px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    line-height:20px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: .4s;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */

}
.subject:hover {
    background-color: #241E4E; 
    color: white; 
    border: 1px solid #555555;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);

}
.subject:focus {
outline:0px;
}

.subjectOK {
  background-color: white; 
    /* border: none; */
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 30%;
    color: black; 
    padding: 1px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor:not-allowed;
    line-height:20px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: .4s;


     -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
     -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
       -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
            user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */

}

.csstr {
 border: 0px solid black;

}


.csstitle {
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="helloApp">
<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
 <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">


<title>AngularJS</title>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>


   
</head>
<!-- Controller name goes here -->
<body ng-controller="CompanyCtrl">
<div ng-app="helloApp" ng-controller="DataCtrl">

 <h2 class="csstitle">Seleccionar Materias</h2>



 <div class="table-responsive">          
   <table class="table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="number in numbers" class="text-center">{{tableTitle}}{{number}}</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr class="csstr" ng-repeat="item in content | limitTo: 7">

         <td> <!-- SEMESTRE #1 -->
          <div id="{{numbers[0]}}" ng-click="reloadData()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[0]}}">{{content[$index].City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S1</div>
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #2 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[1]}}">{{content[$index].City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S2</div>
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #3 -->
            <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[2]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S3</div> 
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #4 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[3]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S4</div> 
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #5 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[4]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S5</div> 
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #6 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[5]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S6</div> 
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #7 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[6]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S7</div> 
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #8 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[7]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S8</div> 
         </td>

         <td><!-- SEMESTRE #9 -->
          <div ng-click="openModal()" class="subject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{numbers[8]}}">{{item.City}} <br/> descripcion <br/> + S9</div> 
         </td>

       </tr>

     </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>



<div ng-repeat="item in numbers | limitTo: 9">
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade modalCloseID" id="myModal{{item}}" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Materia # {{item}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Seleccione un horario.</p>

          

     <label>Filtro</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchKeyword"/> 

      {{content}}
      {{contentWrong}}
     

    <div id="inbox"> 
     <table class="table">
      <tr>
       <th>Name
       </th>
       <th>Employees
       </th>
       <th>Head Office
       </th>
       <th>Acción
       </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="company in companies  | filter: searchKeyword ">
       <td>
        {{company.name}}
       </td>
       <td>
        {{company.employees}}
       </td>
       <td>
        {{company.headoffice}}
       </td>
       <td>
       <input type="button" value="Agregar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="closeModal()" ng-click="addGroup(company.name)" ng-disabled="checked{{item}}"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    

     <button ng-click="reloadData()"> Reload data</button>


    </div> <!-- Contenido dinamico, por cada CLICK -->

  


    </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END MODAL-->
</div>
 



 <hr>
 <h2 class="csstitle">Materias seleccionadas</h2>

 <table class="table">
  <tr>
   <th>Name
   </th>
   <th>Employees
   </th>
   <th>Head Office
   </th>
   <th>Acción
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in vAddGroup">
   <td>
    {{item.name}}
   </td>
   <td>
    {{item.employees}}
   </td>
   <td>
    {{item.headoffice}}
   </td>
   <td>
   <input type="button" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeRow(item.name)"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try deleting cookies and cache on your browser, and be sure you are opening the file you are actually editing!

Comment: It would be a very drastic solution to eliminate everything, I just need to update the content within the Modal.